# QT creator | cmake & qmake configuration error on Windows

Tags: qt, mingw

I am new to QT and trying to configure QT creator on my Windows system

I created cmake configuration project I get below error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\share\cmake-3.24\Modules\CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62: error: The C++ compiler "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program. It fails with the following output: Change Dir: C:/Users/Asus/OneDrive/Documents/build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_6_4_3_MinGW_64_bit_qt_qt6-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/Asus/anaconda3/Library/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_6f661 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f661.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_6f661.exe FAILED: cmTC_6f661.exe cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f661.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_6f661.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_6f661.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ." ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The compilers auto-detected MinGW installed for QT which is in location: `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.exe` and name of the project is untitled2

I tried adding it the compiler manually to QT creator in Preferences, but there no changes. Also, tried building the project using cmake GUI but the error remained same.

I tried creating qmake configuration project with QT creator but got the error as:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_071a3.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_071a3.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-ylyy60\testCXXCompiler.cxx ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong, can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Why does your qmake error talk about CMakeFiles?

Comment: I  am not aware of that, maybe I might have made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue could be related to a problem with your C++ compiler installation or configuration.

Here are some suggestions you can try:

Verify that you have installed the correct version of MinGW for your system, compatible with Qt and your project. Make sure that MinGW's bin folder is added to your system's PATH environment variable.

Check that your C++ compiler is correctly configured in Qt Creator > Options > Kits > Desktop Qt 6.4.3 MinGW 64-bit. Ensure that the compiler path is set correctly, and that the make and debugger paths point to the correct executable files.

Try running a simple C++ test program to make sure that your compiler is working properly. Go to File > New File or Project > Non-Qt Project > Plain C++ Project, build it and run it to see if you have any issues.

Consider rebuilding your project on a new CMake build folder. Remove the build folder and create a new build folder. Run cmake in the new build folder, and build the project again.

You can also try installing a different C++ compiler, such as Microsoft's Visual Studio, and configure Qt Creator to use it instead of MinGW.

Hopefully, one of these suggestions will help you resolve your issue